# Most efficient way to work with HUGE binary matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, boost, xeon-phi, binary-matrix

I have a huge binary matrix, like **100000 x 100000**.

Reading this article http://www.cs.up.ac.za/cs/vpieterse/pub/PieterseEtAl_SAICSIT2010.pdf, I seemed to understand that the best tradeoff to memorize and work with a binary matrix is using **boost::dynamic_bitsets**.

Since in ***"Table 2: Relative time performance of the programs that implemented the data structures"*** :
**std::vector<bool>** is in last position, while **boost::dynamic_bitset** is in first position.

And in ***"Table 3: Relative memory usage of the programs that implemented the data structures"***:
**std::vector<bool>** is in first position, but **boost::dynamic_bitset** is in second position.

Besides, in the paper, at page 7th, there is the following 
statement:

> "Despite the impressive memory performance of std::vector, its dismal time performance renders it unusable in large-scale applications."

And in the conclusions:

> "We have shown that boost::dynamic_bitset is considerably more efficient than most of the other implementations in terms of execution speed, while the implementation using std::vector<char> outperformed the other implementations in terms of memory efficiency."

Now in my case, my target machine is a **XEON PHI**.
My target application is [Game Of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).
I have rappresented the binary matrix as a binary array of ROWS x COLS cells.

I have tried the code with 3 different configurations, bulding them with -the **icpc** compiler with **-O3** optimization flag:

1. **Array of booleans**
2. **Array of booleans + vectorization**, i.e. changing the code using the **Array Notation** as described [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/f0/24/4.1-cilkplus-vectorization.pdf)
3. **boost::dynamic_bitsets**. In this case, I could not change the code using the Array Notation since, when I try, I get the following error:

   ```
   error: base of array section must be pointer or array type
   ```

   same error when using **std::vector<bool>**.

Looking to the performance of just one iteration of the game main loop for a matrix of 100000 x 100000 size, I have found that: **solution 2** works almost six times faster than **solution 1**, but unexpectedly **solution 1** works twice faster than **solution 3**.

In conclusion, I have the following questions to make:

1. What is, in general, the most efficient data structure to store/work with an **HUGE MATRIX** ?
2. Can I do better than *"answer 1"* knowing that my target machine is a **XEON PHI** ?
3. Is it possible to apply **vectorization** to **vector<bool>** or **boost::dynamic_bitsets** ?

Thanks for the answer about the specific target application: Game Of Life.
But what about working with a **huge binary matrix in other context** ?

Comment: You forgot the most important information -- Did you build your program with optimizations turned on?  If not, then this whole post becomes moot.

Comment: Bill Gosper's* paper [Exploiting regularities in large cellular spaces](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/m1/gol/gosper-84.pdf) may be of interest to you.

Comment: *Yes, that's the same Gosper of glider gun fame.

Answer (score 1):

If you **REALLY** care about performance in Conway's game of life, you should switch to a purely bit parallel boolean math design.  The simple task of counting 8 neighbors is annoyingly hard as a parallel boolean operation, but worth the trouble.  The 64-way direct parallelism alone pays back a multiple of the cost of bitwise.

You might have some 128-bit or higher direct parallelism possible on some CPUs with the same basic design.

Once you are using 64-bit or bigger integers instead of bools, all issues of efficiently storing bools become irrelevant.

When I did this in assembler decades ago, I found one important optimization was to share information between successive rows.  When doing that, it became easier to look at the total of a block of nine cells rather than eight neighbors.  So it may help to realize the rules can be compatibly restated:
When there are 3 in its set of 9, a cell turns on (whether it was on before or not).
When there are 4 in its set of 9, a cell is unchanged.
Otherwise it turns off.

The way info was shared across rows heavily depended on the asm language and register set of that machine decades ago.  So you might or might not find looking at the full 9 (instead of 8 neighbors) helps you.

Comment: I think there are vastly faster ways optimize Conway's game of life using memoized/precalculated cell configurations.

Comment: If you care about performance of Life you may want to do this. But if you care with all-caps bold "really", you'll probably want to skip on the micro-optimisation and use Gosper's HashLife algorithm which is likely to make this micro-optimization pointless. HashLife is just at an entirely different scale here.